# Using flink-sql, how to create a table that reads from multiple topics using wildcard/regex

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, flink-sql

I have 2 tables with exactly same structure created in flink-sql application .. lets say

```
CREATE TABLE t1_g1
(
    `id`    INT,
    `name`    STRING
)
    WITH ( 'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 't1.g1',
        'properties.auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
....       );

CREATE TABLE t1_g2
(
    `id`    INT,
    `name`    STRING
)
    WITH ( 'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 't1.g2',
        'properties.auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
....       );
```

Question: Is it possible or supported in flink-sql, if i can create another table that reads from both t1.g1 and t1.g2 topics using some wildcard like..

```
CREATE TABLE t_all
(
    `id`    INT,
    `name`    STRING
)
    WITH ( 'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 't1.*',
        'properties.auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
....       );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You could, for example, set

```
'topic' = 't1.g1;t1.g2'
```

or

```
'topic-pattern' = 't1.*'
```

Note that you'll need to adjust `scan.topic-partition-discovery.interval` if you want the consumer to discover topics created after the job starts running.

The details are described in [the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#topic-and-partition-discovery).